# Content Type is return the null value

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, content-type

When doing upload the file from jsp page. The request.getContentType() and  String type1 = req.getHeader("Content-Type") are return the null value.

Jsp Code:

```
    <FORM action="/UploadServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <INPUT type="file" name="name_of_files">
    <INPUT type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
    </FORM>
```

Comment: what is your desiderata?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. Post your servlet `doPost`.

Comment: OS, Browser of client are? Because that's set by the browser.